# Question about project dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclispe, I know a project's build path can point to another project's output folder. Then I read somewhere that one project can also point to another projects "Referenced Libraries" so that you don't have to define the external jar references over and over. I can't figure out how to get this to work so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

I'm working with version 3.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "Order and Export" tab of the "Build path" dialog, and select which libraries you want to export for other projects to see.

Answer (score 1):

Take project A, and click preferences go to 'Java Build Path', and look at the 'Order and Export' tab.  There there should be a bunch of unchecked checkboxes.  Check all the ones you'd like to export.

Then take project B, go to build properties and make A depend on B, B will then have access to A's dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually set this up myself, but I have worked with project that do work this way.  I *think* you must go to the "Java Build Path" settings for the project that contains the libraries you want to access and under "Order and Export" and select the libraries you would like to make available to dependent projects.  Then I think you can just go to the other project to "Project References" and select the project that contains your libraries.

Hope this helps, I've seen how this is setup before... and think this is all you need to do just never configured it entirely myself.